# How to rewrite two lines into one?

Tags: r

How to write these two lines as a one-liner?

```
which.max(WHO$Under15) ## output is 124
WHO$Country[124] ## output is "Niger"
```

When I enter `which.max(WHO$Under15)` I get the country number, which is 124. I then enter the country number in `WHO$Country[]` to get the country, which is Niger. I am wondering how to simplify this code to one line.

Comment: Not clear about the question.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
WHO$Country[which.max(WHO$Under15)]
```

will do what you want, or

```
with(WHO,Country[which.max(Under15)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I kept entering the code WHO$Country[which.max(Who$Under15)]. This clarified it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
subset(WHO, Under15 == max(Under15), "Country",drop = TRUE)
```

Or if you're using *data.table*

```
WHO[which.max(Under15), Country]
```